# Как работать с mercurial через прокси?

Tags: прокси

Попытка загрузки кода

```
hg clone -r release https://go.googlecode.com/hg/ go
```

выдает ошибку

```
abort: error: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно прописать параметры прокси в файле ~/.hgrc

```
[http_proxy]
host=сервер:порт
```